# Travis OS X test Postgres

Tags: macos, postgresql, travis-ci

How can I set Postgres in Travis CI OS X build?

I can't start and I don't know how to set these:

```
--dbaddress localhost --dbport 5432 --dbname testDb --dbusername postgres
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Travis CI OS X instances the environment is similar to a typical [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installation.

Here is the [Travis CI OS X environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/) you can configure.

The database services that are available:

postgis version 2.1.3, postgresql version 9.3.5

Unlike Linux, the service configuration is not currently available in OSX. You start a database service using the install script and making use of the Postgresql tools directly.

An example .travis.yml looks like this:

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"
language:
  - objective-c
os:
  - osx
sudo:
  - false
install:
   - export PG_DATA=$(brew --prefix)/var/postgres
   - pg_ctl -w start -l postgres.log --pgdata ${PG_DATA}
   - createuser -s postgres
   - psql -c 'create database testDb;' -U postgres
   - cat postgres.log
```

So what does it do?

“add ons” is selecting your specific postgresql version over the default

“sudo” commands cannot be executed in Travis CI

“install” contains the commands we need to run and others you want to add

The pg_ctl command requires a data directory, “PG_DATA” contains a path to the local home-brew installation and your directory to store database files.

pg_ctl will start the existing service and wait(-w) to be connected.

A unix user/role "postgres" must be created and is used in the final creation script for your database “testDb”.

Finally, the postgres.log is sent to Travis CI log.

Hopefully, that gives you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it, but I've got an error:  

$ if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then pg_ctl -w start -l postgres.log —pgdata ${PG_DATA}; fi   

pg_ctl: too many command-line arguments (first is "—pgdata")   Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.   

The command "if [[ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]]; then pg_ctl -w start -l postgres.log —pgdata ${PG_DATA}; fi" failed and exited with 1 during . Your build has been stopped.

Comment: I have updated the answer to contain a minimum working version in Travis CI. Perhaps you can try and see if it works for your case?

Comment: Looks like the command is invalid as you have them separated by a dash "-", should split them up or just use && e.g.  `createuser -s postgres && psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres && cat postgres.log;`

Comment: Currently that error is occurring when using Xcode 7 or higher. Xcode 6.4 seems to start up.

Comment: You are right, it works on Xcode 6.4. But it cause that clang3.7 is not installed. Do you know how can install it? I googled it but I only find that I need to use higher version of Xcode, but I can't.

Answer (score 3):

Additional information to griffio's answer:

In the meantime Travis is running PostgreSQL 9.5 (even with addon postgresql: "9.4") and I got the following log output when starting:

```
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.4, which is not compatible with this version 9.5.4.
```

It's working after creating a new cluster first:

```
install:
   - export PG_DATA=$(brew --prefix)/var/postgres
   - rm -rf $PG_DATA
   - initdb $PG_DATA -E utf8
   - pg_ctl -w start -l postgres.log --pgdata ${PG_DATA}
   - createuser -s postgres
   - psql -c 'create database testDb;' -U postgres
```